# Hiding sections using IF field code and properly updating the Table of Contents

Tags: ms-word

My document has a number of collapsible sections and the table of contents is built automatically from them. The field code used for the ToC is `{ TOC \o "1-3" \h \z \u }`.

If I conditionally exclude one of the sections (by using something like `{ IF { DOCPROPERTY x } = 1 "Entire section goes in here" "" }`, where x != 1), then the table of contents is not properly updated. Instead of deleting the corresponding entry from the ToC, it replaces it's number with 1.1. How do I fix that?

EDIT:

I've posted a screenshot of the table of contents with the section titles redacted at [imgur.com/a/5FfT9KK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwJY5.jpg)

Also, I posted the same question on the superuser forum (a few days ago) but no one replied https://superuser.com/questions/1518915/hiding-sections-using-if-field-code-and-properly-updating-the-table-of-contents

Comment: Could you share a couple of relevant screen shots, please? Right off-hand, I don't see any way to change this short of applying a non-Heading style to the text, which means simple field codes, alone, won't do the job. But it would help to see exactly how the document content is formatted (the numbering, especially). Note, also, that you might have better chances with this on an end-user site, such as Super User. It's not completely off-topic, here, but that's where you'd find the people who work more intensively in this area.

Comment: Thanks Cindy. I posted the same question on the superuser forum (a few days ago) but no one replied. I've posted a screenshot of the table of contents with the section titles redacted at https://imgur.com/a/5FfT9KK

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link under the question to include the picture (use the tool in the editor) as well as the link to the Super User question with a remark that you've tried there. (The other Q, as well, please.)

Comment: Please use the EDITOR's tool to bring in the picture - that link won't insert correctly.